# Why does this not work (Java)? (Arrays into Arraylist of type int)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

What is the correct code for this applet I'm working on? I just need to add the arrays of type int into the Arraylist...the bold is the main problem (If the rest works... -__-)!

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.applet.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BinomialExpander extends JApplet implements ActionListener 
{ 
     JLabel lblFahrenheit; 
     JLabel lblCelsius; 
     JLabel outputCelsius; 
     JTextField txtFahrenheit; 
     double degreesFahrenheit; 
     FlowLayout layout;
     ArrayList<int[]> pascalsT = new ArrayList<int[]>();
     private int[] pascal1 = {1,1};
     private int[] pascal2 = {1,2,1};
     private int[] pascal3 = {1,3,3,1};
     private int[] pascal4 = {1,4,6,4,1};
     private int[] pascal5 = {1,5,10,10,5,1};
     private int[] pascal6 = {1,6,15,20,15,6,1};
     private int[] pascal7 = {1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1};
     private int[] pascal8 = {1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1};
     private int[] pascal9 = {1,9,36,84,126,84,36,9,1};
     private int[] pascal10 = {1,10,45,120,210,120,45,10,1};
...
}
```

Comment: OK,now that I've formatted your code: where is the actual problem? I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: What do you mean, 'does not work'. Looks fine to me. Of course, pascalsT is not having any relations with the various pascals.

Comment: As @Makoto suggests, you need to add objects to your ArrayList for it to be useful.

Comment: most of this is unnecessary what (I think) is be asked is whether something like http://pastebin.com/s9RN03mB actually works.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, you just want to put the array values into the list.

Add the following after all your declarations:

```
{
    pascals.add(pascal1);
    pascals.add(pascal2);
    ...
}
```

Or, you could add these statements in your constructor.  This particular syntax is what is called an instance initializer.  It runs before your constructor, and you can have them anywhere in the class, and it will run in the order declared.  In fact, you can interleave them with your variable declarations, but I believe the variable has to be declared above the instance initializer in which it is referred to.

As a side note, having an instance variable with an assignment is essential the same thing.

```
private Integer a = new Integer(1);
```

is functionally identical to

```
private Integer a;
{ a = new Integer(1); }
```

Answer (score -2):

The Array to ArrayList conversion is done this way, try this out:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};

List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Comment: How does this solve the original poster's (yet to be fully defined) problem?

Comment: I have given him the way to convert the array to arraylist. Instead of negating the things try to solve it... if you cant pls try to appreciate the solution

Comment: I can't solve it til he clarifies it. But your solution doesn't appear to be related to his questions or concerns. And I have given him a useful suggestion in my comment.

Comment: why the for loop? it does not even process the ArrayList